# Best way/pattern to build request based on different service

Tags: java, python, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

I have a about 20 different services which I have to send requests to which require a slightly different set of headers.

The bad legacy code is something like this,

```
row = db.query_for_service()

if row.type == 'foo1'
   // add common headers to request
   // add foo1 specific headers 1
   // add foo1 specific header 2
   // add foo1 specific header 3
else if row.type == 'foo2'
   // add common headers to request
   // add foo2 specific header 1
...
...
...
else if row.type == foo20
   // add common headers to request
   // add foo20 specific header 1
   // add foo20 specific header 2 
   // ...

send_request()
```

What is the best way to refactor this? I have considered some patterns that may work here (strategy, builder) but I am not too sure.

I am currently learning both Java and Python and I would to get thoughts on how the solutions would differ in the two languages

Comment: Can the person who downvoted explain why I was downvoted? I am trying to use this question to improve my code and figure out how I can refactor this old code to be more manageable. If this isn't the appropriate place to ask this type of question, then where should I ask this question?

Comment: Can you give some sample input data, I'm not sure I really understand what's being retrieved from the db/what requests are being constructed/what's being requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, what I would do is something along these lines.

```
#Put this in the initialisation 
Map foos<row.type,String> = new Map<row.type, String>()
#Populate the map 
map.set('a') = 'headerA specific params x=1'
map.set('b') = 'headerB specific params x=2'
map.set('c') = 'headerC specific params y=3'
map.set ...

Map bars<String,String> = new Map<String,String()
bars.set('fooA') = 'a,b'
bars.set('fooB') = 'a,c'
String commonheader = "HTTP/1.1"


#This would be in a method    
row = db.query_for_service()
String output_header += commonheader
for i in bars.get(fooN).split(','):
    output_header += foos.get(i)
send_request()
```

In sort of pseudo java/python. The map would be pre-filled with everything you need, then just pick out what you want and attach.

Comment: but I have a set of different headers I have to attach for each different foos. Do I attach one giant string? Would we have duplicates for each foo then?

Comment: Questions: is each fooN's headers distinct from every other fooN? Is there an overriding reason (i.e.you're inserting stuff) to not attach it in a single string? It sounds like what's done currently is that each fooN has a distinct set of headers to attach. This solution just refactors the headers from each if statement into a map, and then attaches them based on fooN, making for a cleaner solution without the IFs.

Comment: While there are headers that are common to all requests, FooN can contain any combination of headers from a list of available headers. So Foo1 could have A,B,C headers, Foo2 can have A,C and Foo3 could have D.

Comment: @sasker, is this the correct answer, or are you still looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

You should try pattern [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

The pseudo code something like this:

```
interface Command(){
  void execute();
}

class ConcreteCommandA() implements Command {
  @Override
  void execute(){
    // action 1
  }
}


class ConcreteCommandB() implements Command {
  @Override
  void execute(){
    // action 2
  }
}
```

and use this structure in your client:

```
Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<String, Command>;
  commands.put("action1", new ConcreteCommandA());
  commands.put("action2", new ConcreteCommandB());

runCommand(String str){
  Command command = commands.get(str);
  command.execute();
}
```

and so on

Comment: What would the "command" be for my case? buildFoo1Request, buildFoo2Request, buildFoo3Request... etc?

Comment: command is an interface. and each type of your request encapsulate different object that implements command. It simplifies other tasks like a save history of your action, undo/redo operation etc.

Comment: sorry I didn't mean command, I meant ConcreteCommand. How does it correspond to my example?

Comment: You should create objects with method execute() that has your actual implementation of some command. I don't know python good so i gave you example on java

Comment: But even in Java, what do you think my ConcreteCommands should be?

Comment: It depends on what you need. For Example you have "login" command, you create class LoginCommand implements Command and add actual implementation of your login logic in the execute method. In your case i assume you can extract method `// add common headers to request` to abstract method to avoid code duplication, and for each method use specific implementation